# How do I style a specific select option in HTML

Tags: html, css

This is what my code looks like:

```
<select>
  <option>
    PRODUCT CATALOUGE
  </option>

  <option>
    VACUUM COMPONENTS
  </option>

  <option>
    VALVE COMPONENTS
  </option>

  <option>
    ROUGHING COMPONENTS
  </option>

  <option>
    VACUUM MEASUREMENT
  </option>

  <option>
    GLASS COMPONENTS
  </option>

  <option>
    ELECTRICAL FEEDTHROUGHS
  </option>

  <option>
    MOTION AND MANIPULATION
  </option>

  <option>
    THIN FILM PRODUCTS
  </option>
</select>
```

Any here is my CSS:

```
select { 
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px; 

  width: 220px;
  text-indent: 27px;
  font-family: Palatino Linotype;
  font-size: 15px;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #ccc, 0 -1px #2961c1 inset;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #ccc, 0 -1px #2961c1 inset;

  position:absolute; top: 10%; left: 2%;
}
```

This code actually works fine however I want to make a new drop-down list using the select option but I want to style it differently. I tried using a div tag and setting an ID in the external style sheet but that doesn't work. How do i go about styling that specific select function?

e.g. #select or do i need to use a class?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
#menu1 { 
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px; 

  width: 220px;
  text-indent: 27px;
  font-family: Palatino Linotype;
  font-size: 15px;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #ccc, 0 -1px #2961c1 inset;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #ccc, 0 -1px #2961c1 inset;

  position:absolute; top: 10%; left: 2%;
}
#menu2 { 
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px; 

  width: 220px;
  text-indent: 27px;
  font-family: Palatino Linotype;
  font-size: 15px;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #ccc, 0 -1px #2961c1 inset;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #ccc, 0 -1px #2961c1 inset;

  position:absolute; top: 10%; left: 2%;
}
```

and use id menu1 for first and menu2 for second select tag means give ID to each select tag

Comment: I added an ID to the drop-down list however that just breaks the code, it seems like my external style sheet doesn't like having to use #

Comment: can you create fiddle link of it so that I can directly help you out

Comment: It works fine in the Fiddle but when I implement it my code remains broken

Comment: That's not working either, I don't understand why though. It's the same as yours

Comment: maybe because of position

Comment: the cod just isn't recognizing the CSS stylings

Answer (score 1):

I would say use classes, they can be used again if you need another `select` with same look.

One other great reason for using classes is that you can apply them in layers, since you can apply more than a single class to any element. For example,

> Let’s take a look at buttons, for example. Say we want all of our buttons to have a font size of 16 pixels, but we want the background color of our buttons to vary depending on where the buttons are used. We can create a few classes and layer them on an element as necessary to apply the desired styles.
>
> HTML
>
> ```
> <a class="btn btn-danger">...</a>
> <a class="btn btn-success">...</a>
> ```
>
> CSS

```
.btn {
     font-size: 16px;
}
.btn-danger {
    background: red;
}
.btn-success {
    background: green;
}
```

> Here you can see two anchor elements, both with multiple class attribute values. The first class, btn, is used to apply a font size of 16 pixels to each of the elements. Then, the first anchor element uses an additional class of btn-danger to apply a red background color while the second anchor element uses an additional class of btn-success to apply a green background color. Our styles here are clean and modular.
>
> [multiple classes - learn.shayhowe.com](http://learn.shayhowe.com/html-css/getting-to-know-css/#multiple-classes)

**Now as for you question, you could do something like this,**

HTML

```
<select class='my-select-1'>
    <option>....</option>
    .....................
</select>

<select class='my-select-2'>
    <option>....</option>
    .....................
</select>
```

CSS

```
.my-select-1 {
    /* properties for first select */
}

.my-select-2 {
    /* properties for second select */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<select id="one">
  <option>
    PRODUCT CATALOUGE
  </option>

  ...

  <option>
    THIN FILM PRODUCTS
  </option>
</select>

<select id="two">
  <option>
    PRODUCT CATALOUGE
  </option>

  ...

  <option>
    THIN FILM PRODUCTS
  </option>
</select>
```

This is a working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/e63fzbkt/

You can also use classes instead of ids.